# Keyboard shortcut to override parent constructor in PhpStorm

Tags: constructor, phpstorm, code-generation

is it possible to override constructor in PHPStorm by a single keyboard shortcut?
Using "generate constructor" in child class gives me a blank one, while "generate override methods -> (find and click the parent constructor) ->" is not very comfortable for a thing I do many times every day. Thanks.

Comment: Create and use custom Live Template (e.g. `oc[tab]` (for example) would generate body for such overridden method) -- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm . Unfortunately you cannot assign custom shortcut to specific live template .. but pressing 3 keys (as in my example) does not take that long (faster that using existing dialog windows for sure).

Comment: On another hand this your statement: *"while "generate override methods -> (find and click the parent constructor)"* -- no need to use mouse -- quick search works just fine so it can be done using keyboard only.